# SQL MERGE based on the value of a particular column

Tags: sql-server, merge

I have a scenario where I need to merge data into a SQL table using two different rules. 
- If the 'Type' column of the incoming row is 'A', I need to merge using columns 'Alpha', 'Bravo' 
- If the value of 'Type' is 'B', then I need to merge using columns 'Charlie', 'Delta'

Is there a better way to do this than write two separate merge statements, one checking for 'A' and the other for 'B'?

Comment: Are you sure you even want/need to use MERGE? [You should read this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

Comment: Can you show a small data sample of your data and what you want to accomplish? It would be better for us to help you with that information.

Comment: Thank you! Here is a concrete example of what I am trying to achieve:
Let's say this is the input dataset (with column headers)
Type  Alpha  Bravo  Charlie  Delta   Echo  Foxtrot
=======================================
A        A1        B1       C1        D1      E1      F1
B        A3        B3       C3        D3      E3      F3
B        A4        B4       C4        D4      E4      F4

Now for the first row, since the "Type" column == "A", I want to merge on "Alpha" and "Bravo" as the primary keys. For the next two rows, I want to merge with "Charlie", "Delta" as PKs.

Comment: (contd.) I want to convert my MERGE into something like:

MERGE <output>
USING <input>  ON  (<input>.Type = 'A' AND <output>.Type = 'A' AND <input>.Alpha = <output>.Alpha AND <input>.Bravo = <output>.Bravo) -- merge those rows ---

alternately

MERGE <output>
USING <input>  ON  (<input>.Type = 'B' AND <output>.Type = 'B' AND <input>.Charlie = <output>.Charlie AND <input>.Delta = <output>.Delta) -- merge those rows ---